# axios post in expo (react native) results in Network Error, works in android but error on ios only

Tags: react-native, rest, axios, expo

Problem:
Tring to call backend api using axios in expo ios results in
"Error: Network Error", same code works in android simulator.

```
try {
      const result = await axios.post("https://api.abc.com" +'/send', data);

    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error is-->", error);
    }
```

background:
www.abc.com(registered in godaddy) has wordpress which is hosted in godaddy iteself. godaddy ssl is used and on .htaccess in wordpress site redirect from http to https is used.

on godaddy.com itself dns is used where i have A record for subdomain [www.api.abc.com](http://www.api.abc.com) which points to droplet in digital ocean.

So, at the moment same "https://api.abc.com/send" along with body params works while tested with postman, but does not works with ios(again it also works with android).

any help for this "network error" is appreciated.

Comment: check if your link is http or https

Comment: @Engr.AftabUfaq https://api.abc.com/send is working on Postman on post call, 

also backend is reached on get request from browser.... so i believe https is working,
can it be http to https redirect in .htaccess in wordpress site....my take is ios might be seeing http first and then redirected to https second, i do not know if that is the case.... any other reasons? any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

just add the following line in your info.plist file

```
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
```

your **info.plis**t file would look like this: Like this

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Comment: i am using expo and have not ejected to use bare workflow, so changing info.plist is not an option for me.... any other solution for expo app please